# Get wall_post and profile data for several users

Tags: mysql, query, performance, query-performance

I'm trying to build a query for fetch wall_posts and profile fields for several user_id. First see the images at: http://www.dropmocks.com/mBjQ7P. The table with id_user_rq, id_user_ap is the table where I handle the relations. Meaning 1 and 2 are friends and 1 and 3 are friends too because the directionality is 1,2 | 2,1 and 1,3 | 3,1. So what I need here is to get the wall_post for users 1,2,3 and also the profile data for the same users. Wall_posts is image #2 and profile is the first image. I've tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    default_profiles.*,default_wall_posts.*,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) - default_wall_posts.date_created AS pass_time
FROM
    (default_wall_posts)
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles
    ON (default_profiles.user_id = default_wall_posts.userid) 
    AND (default_wall_posts.userid = 2 OR default_wall_posts.userid = 3)
WHERE
    default_wall_posts.userid = 1 AND
    (
        default_wall_posts.userid = 2 AND
        default_wall_posts.userid = 3
    )
ORDER BY
    default_wall_posts.date_created DESC;
```

But it's not working because I only get the wall_posts and profile fields for user 1. What I'm doing wrong?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    default_profiles.*,default_wall_posts.*,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) - default_wall_posts.date_created AS pass_time
FROM
    (default_wall_posts)
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles
    ON (default_profiles.user_id = default_wall_posts.userid) 
    AND (default_wall_posts.userid = 2 OR default_wall_posts.userid = 3)
WHERE
    default_wall_posts.userid = 1 AND
    (
        default_wall_posts.userid = 2 AND
        default_wall_posts.userid = 3
    )
ORDER BY
    default_wall_posts.date_created DESC;
```

The WHERE is impossible to fulfill because default_wall_posts.userid not be 1 and 2 and 3 at the same time.

Try these changes

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    default_profiles.*,default_wall_posts.*,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) - default_wall_posts.date_created AS pass_time
FROM
    (default_wall_posts)
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles
    ON (default_profiles.user_id = default_wall_posts.userid) 
WHERE
    default_wall_posts.userid IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY
    default_wall_posts.date_created DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks @rolandomysqldba you're right the WHERE will never happen because the AND maybe with a OR should work anyway your query is right and I use that instead of mine.